Common mode choke rated current
I have ordered a common mode choke (https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/emc/emc/cmf_cmc/data_sheet/30/db/ind_2008/b82721s0.pdf) to reduce the common mode noise available on the 5V DC power line in one of my project. The datasheet specifies for the rated current a value of 2.7A. My application draw a balanced current of max. 1.6A DC. When I insert the CMC in the power line, my application current is reduced to 1.5A.
Using a CMC with a rated current of 2A, the application current reduced to approx. 1A.
It means that in my case  the rated current of desired choke need to have min. twice of the application current (3.2A)?
Can anyone tell me if my assumption is correct or not?
Here is how i've connected the common mode choke.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I measured the current through the wire from ext. power adapter through a self made current probe ant the current looks like this:


My take is that the winding resistance is having an effect. A 2.7A rated part will get a bit warm at 1.6A loading.

I suspect that the circuit is oscillating. Please add a circuit diagram to the question. You can use Circuit Lab tool in the toolbar of the question editor.

@Peter Smith yes the part get a bit warm, but the big issue is why the current is reduced.

@RussellH I've not seen any oscillation. Maybe the CMC is going to saturate?

TDK (https://product.tdk.com/en/contact/faq/emc-components-0040.html) defines the rated current of CMC as the temperature rise of the product (ΔT) that occurs when current is applied to all lines. Having two lines means it to divide by 2?

For testing purposes i've used as a load a simple power resistor and in this case i've not observed any limitation for the current.  So perhaps some oscillations but not voltage, maybe current. I will try to measure with a current probe.

I measured the current through the wires and it looks like in the picture above. It's oscillate. How can i damp or eliminate this?

What are the source and load, actually? You show a passive resistor, but that cannot oscillate. Please show a complete schematic. Also include some discussion of what you're doing here: why do you need a CMC? What are you selecting it based on? Why are you measuring the DC voltage? What other effects does it have, what else might be important?

Ok, i will try to give more details about the whole thing.
I've developed a medical device which acquires vital parameters (ECG, Respiration and SpO2/Plethysmogram) and show them on LCD.
The device can be powered over the built in Li-ION battery or an external 5V power adapter.
When connecting the ext. power adapter, the battery will be also charged if required.
The acquisition of ECG and Respiration is done over 3 electrodes on the skin.  When the device is enterily powered by baterry the parameter curves shown on LCD are clear.

When the ext. power adapter is connected and the battery is charging (with the max. of 1.3A) than the respiration curve get distorted.
I've measured through a current clamp (over each line separately and together of the ext. power supply adapter) the differential and common mode noise.
I found that the differential mode noise predominate.
The FFT of the noise have a peak at approx. 22kHz.
The impedance of the source and the load is unknown.
The load in my circuit represents the max. current drawn from the power supply adapter when the device is on and the battery will be charged.
